# Is the Yearling badge one day late

Tags: support, badges

I think the title says it all.

My first post is dated 2010-08-10 00:24:47Z.
I received the yearling badge at 2011-08-11 00:16:33Z.

Shouldn't this have been awarded 2011-08-10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not based on first post, it's based on the time of account creation.

Mouse over the date in the "member for" field to see the UTC time your account was created.

Comment: In my case: Member since 2010-08-10 00:07:42Z, so my point is still valid.

Comment: The badge grants also run sporadically, so it's possible that the run for that badge just happened to be a little past the 24 hour window.. does it really *matter?*

Comment: It uses `GETUTCDATE() / 365.242199` because of leap years.

Comment: Well that explains is all :)   Just to be clear: It doesn't really matter at all!  I'm just reporting the issues I stumble upon while I use the site.  It is, after all, still in Beta mode.  It's up to you if you want to stuff it into FogBugz or if you want to feed Joel's dust bunnies with it...

Comment: BTW: _You_ have been a member since 2010-08-09 18:46:52Z.  Don't you wonder where your silver badge is?  ;-)

Comment: This also requires a certain amount of rep per year, as specified on the badge itself.. are you done now? can we move on to *productive work* now, or shall we waste more time here? :) http://ux.stackexchange.com/badges/52/yearling

Comment: LOL.  Roger that.  I'm off!